# C++ specific UML modelling of pointers/references

Tags: c++, uml

In C++ value types implicitely are of the strongest association, but I can imagine the followoing five relations between classes when pointers/references are used (odered by strength of aggregation):

```
 information level     +------+------+------+------+
 v           ownership>| none | weak |shared|unique|
+----------------------+------+------+------+------+
|knows/includes/uses   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   |
+----------------------+------+------+------+------+
|passes/forward declare|  1   |  --  |  --  |  --  |
+----------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

Some of them may not fit into the intention of UML(e.g. 1). But imho it would be desireable to see the measure of coupling of my design. How do this five types of association fit into a class diagram. What is common practice for notation this associations?

This is what I think so far:

1. ??
2. Directed association - arrow.
3. Aggregation - hollow diamond.[1]
4. Aggregation - hollow diamond.[1]
5. Composition - filled diamond.

[1] Unclear.If there is one filled diamond, all hollow diamonds indicate a weak ownership. But if there is no dedicated owner weak and shared references can not be distinguished. Or is the weak ownership conceptually the same as no ownership?

Comment: Only Java fits into UML. You're out of luck.

Comment: Hehe. LOL. I guess you should not be too focused on exact connectors. Associations will do in most cases unless you have some smart code generation which needs that info.

Comment: Well in highly polymorhic and [dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) builds one really has to keep an eye on memorymanagment. Remember its c++ not Java. Dont know what is to lol about RAII and exception safety.

Comment: The LOL referred to "Only Java", not your question.

Answer (score 0):

UML does, on purpose, not offer language specific concepts. Using UML you should model your system for a given problem domain. Language specifics are left to the person implementing the model.

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules in UML about  how to interprete the semantic differences between the various types of relations, and especially not on how to translate constructions in a certain programming language to UML.

But there are some best practices in the industry. I've documented some of the those best practices on my website.

- [UML Composition vs Aggregation vs Association](http://bellekens.com/2010/12/20/uml-composition-vs-aggregation-vs-association/)
- [UML Best Practice: Attribute or Association](http://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/)

In your case I would also consider using a Dependency. That is probably the weakest link in UML. I often use that when I want to visually emphasize usage of a type in one of the Parameters or Attributes